# How MIUI releases based on different Android versions have same features?

Tags: rom, android-versions, miui

I would like to know how MIUI can provide features on all devices that have the same version of MIUI on it, without the same Android version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android version is mainly developed by Google. OEMs like Xiaomi modify AOSP to inject their own features. Other OEMs like Samsung, Huawei also do the same but they don't make visual changes as much as Xiaomi does. Even community based ROMs like Lineage, Omni and their offshoots like AOSP Extended, Resurrection Remix also have an almost standard set of modifications which they do to every AOSP release.

You can also customize AOSP to build a ROM of your own choice with required features.

Comment: But if LineageOS releases version 17 it is Android 10(as base) but by MIUI it is not compellingly the latest Android base, like MIUI 11 is not in every case Android 10 but all phones who has MIUI 11 have the same functions

Comment: @lucki1000 they have teams of thousands of developers - in-office and online - who work on every new upcoming MIUI release for months to add new features. They work on every Android base separately for every targeted device. Beta versions are released before stable one for testing. MIUI 11 development was started back at start of 2019 and it's released now in October.